# Nextjs page routes. How to have folder/id/folder

Tags: next.js

I am trying to have a routes system like

Go to a user page:

```
users/id
```

Go to a users profile page:

```
users/id/profile
```

Go to a page which lists all users:

```
users
```

How can I do this in nextjs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to achieve it. Here is one approach:

```
pages
_ index.js
_ users
_ _ index.js
_ _ [...id].js // match user detail pages and user profile pages
```

See further details about dynamic routing here: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 0):

The documentation can be found [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) and the official example can be found [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing).

#### users/id

```js
# /pages/users/[id]/index.tsx

import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const User: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  return <h1>User: {id}</h1>;
};

export default User;
```

#### users/id/profile

```js
# /pages/users/[id]/[profile].tsx

import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const User: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id, profile } = router.query;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>User: {id}</h1>;
      <h1>Profile: {profile}</h1>;
    </>
  );
};

export default User;
```

#### users

```js
# pages/users/index.tsx

import type { NextPage } from "next";

const Users: NextPage = () => {
  return <h1>Users</h1>;
};

export default Users;
```